# How can I redirect to the correct url using stringex and acts_as_url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I  have a model that uses acts_as_url and in my controller I want to redirect to the model after saving the model in "new". `redirect_to @mymodel` just takes me to `/mycontroller/1` and not  to `/mycontroller/nice-long-url`

Comment: Did you override to_param in your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the to_param method in your model and used a named route:

```
# Inside your model
def to_param
  url # or whatever you set :url_attribute to
end
```

`redirect_to mymodel_path(@mymodel)`